# What modules is Vue.js missing that Angular 2 has?

Tags: javascript, angular, vue.js, vuejs2

What features/modules does **Vue.js** lack that Angular 2/4 has? I'm considering investing in learning **Vue.js** and possibly using it on my next project. I've seen a lot about the features it has, but I need to know what I would be losing before I can make the leap so I can figure out if I can live without it or if there are complementary frameworks/libraries that can fill the gap.

**Edit**

To those voting to close this question as "Too broad", I'm not asking for a complete list of differences, just the features like routing, injection, transclusion, etc.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+vs+vue&oq=angular+vs+vue&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.2382j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I guess a more appropriate question is what features can't you live without? Vue has an official router, transclusion is accomplished via slots, injection is not quite handled the same way but there is now provide/inject. Vue's typescript story is evolving but probably not as good as Angular. Vue is faster, less opinionated. As a former Angular 1 dev, Vue was *far* easier to learn.

Comment: "I'm not asking for a complete list of differences, just the features like routing, injection, transclusion, etc." That's still too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularJS has strong opinions on how an application should be structured i.e. routing e.t.c. Vue's sole purpose is to be a framework on the View layer.

The Vue community has contributed to solving the other common problems around developing SPAs i.e.

- For routing: vue-router
- For state management: vuex
- For HTTP requests: axios, vue-resource e.t.c

**For futher reading:**

- [Comparison between Vue.js and Angular1](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/comparison.html#AngularJS-Angular-1)
- [A curated list of awesome things related to Vue.js](https://github.com/search?q=vue-awesome&type=Everything&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1)